# How to specify test and suite names in maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: maven, testng

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >  
<suite name="SuiteName" verbose="1" >
  <test name="TestName1" >
    <classes>
       <class name="NoPackageTest" />
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="TestName2">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.sample.ParameterSample"/>
      <class name="test.sample.ParameterTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Could someone let me know how I can specify SuiteName, TestName1 and TestName2 in maven-surefire-plugin.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Its enough to set surefire to run your suite, which will in turn run the belonging test classes, you can do it by configuring as follows

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/SuiteName.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Yes, I have been doing the same via pom.xml, I want to see the name of suite and test(s) in report, so I am looking for it.

Thanks